# pygame window doesn't load fill

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to pygame. Also using virtual environment and runing the script from BASH. I can make the pygame window show up but I can't change the background color nor draw a line. It just loads a black screen. Also I tried both **flip()** and **update()** both with same results and if I  **print()** the events they seeem to be occuring just fine. Any ideas?

```
import pygame,sys

#setup
pygame.init()
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

#colors
BLACK =(  0,  0,  0)
WHITE =(255,255,255)
GREEN =(  0,255,  0)
RED   =(255,  0,  0)
BLUE  =(  0,  0,255)
#screen
screen_width=1200
screen_heigth=700
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_heigth))
pygame.display.set_caption ("test_game")


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()          
    screen.fill(GREEN)
    pygame.draw.line(screen,GREEN,[0,100],[100,100],5)
pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: `pygame.display.flip()` and `clock.tick(60)` should be inside the `while True:` loop; issue with indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done this and i got a lime green screen so it seems like that might of fixed it.

```
import pygame,sys

#setup
pygame.init()
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

#colors
BLACK =(  0,  0,  0)
WHITE =(255,255,255)
GREEN =(  0,255,  0)
RED   =(255,  0,  0)
BLUE  =(  0,  0,255)
#screen
screen_width=1200
screen_heigth=700
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_heigth))
pygame.display.set_caption ("test_game")


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()          
    screen.fill(GREEN)
    pygame.draw.line(screen,GREEN,[0,100],[100,100],5)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Yup, it did, thanks. As @Matiiss commented it was an indentation problem with the 'flip()' command. Couldn't accept the answer since it was a comment but I apprecite both answers. Would upvote if I could.